# Find duplicate entries on two (or more) columns and delete the least recent ones

Tags: mysql

I made a big mistake. For some reason, I have forgotten to apply unique index on a table where entries are being edited. This means my table now contains many duplicates.

The best I can do is to pick the duplicates and delete all but those with largest ID.

The table structure looks like this:

[image: My table structure]

The `inzerat` entry represents article ID, the `lang` represents the description language. Obviously, there's just one text for every article and language. But I can't even create the index now:

[image: #1062 - Duplicate entry '33-NULL' for key 'Inzerat']

The `NULL` result must be some kind of nonsense - all `lang` values contain either `cs`, `en` or `ru`.

[image: image description]

Anyways what I need is to **delete every but the latest entry** for every duplicate group. The entry with largest `id` is considered the latest and shall not be deleted.

I even failed to get actual duplicate entries as list:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) c FROM inzerat_popis GROUP BY inzerat,lang HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY `inzerat_popis`.`inzerat` ASC
```

[image: image description]

The entries are grouped, hiding the individual `id`s.

Please try to answer with as general answer as possible. There are already questions and answers about this topic on StackOverflow but all are so localised that I don't know how to use them in my case.

Comment: `The NULL result must be some kind of nonsense` That is not true due your table structure, the field lang does allow NULL VALUES so, must have some registry with that.

Comment: On my localhost, it properly throws out the value, eg. `34-cs`.

Comment: Try selecting as this `select * from yourtable where lang is null` and see what it returns.

Comment: Nothing. I tested that already using the Search tab. It's really weird.

Comment: really weird... try `select distinct lang from yourtable` if you say that only have tree possible values you will see something different.

Comment: I already deleted 400 duplicate rows - I'm now unsure how to test for the problem anymore (it only appeared on that error message). Sorry for this, but the system is online and needed fast fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the `delete` using a `join` along with the ids you want to keep:

```
delete p
    from inzerat_popis p left join
         (select inzerat, lang, max(id) as maxid
          from inzerat_popis p
          group by inzerat, lang
         ) il
         on p.id = il.maxid
    where il.maxid is null;
```

I would recommend running the equivalent `select` statement to be sure this does what want.  To see the ones being deleted, use:

```
    select p.*
    from inzerat_popis p left join
         (select inzerat, lang, max(id) as maxid
          from inzerat_popis p
          group by inzerat, lang
         ) il
         on p.id = il.maxid
    where il.maxid is null
```

Comment: You saved me, thanks. It worked exactly as I needed.